# why runing HttpClient the first time is slow but much faster then?

Tags: java, httpclient

the code is( I write a tool class although solrj will do better) :

```
     for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
       SolrClient client = new SolrClient(new DefaultHttpClient());
       System.out.println(client.fetchFrom(URL, new SolrQuery("cc","id")));
       Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
```

the first it took:
HTTP:294----DONE:326 (MS)

but then it only takes about 20MS to get this done.

Does JVM cache the http result?
when I run it again.The result is just like this.

Comment: I would assume the name lookup for the URL is cached, and maybe the client connection is persistent. Try adding a `client.close();` at the bottom of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time, the server's name has to be resolved to an IP address and a TCP connection has to be created. On subsequent requests, the connection can usually be reused. And even if the connection cannot be reused, the IP address is likely still cached.

Comment: I put the tool class into real project and it runs fast(get singleton `HttpClient`from spring)